# proving existence of continuous function (complicated with ln)

Tags: calculus, continuity, logarithms

me is trying to answer this complicate question.

question is: let $h(x)$ be continuous function on I that contains $x=0$ and $h(0)=0, h(x)>-1, h(x) \neq 0$.

$f(x)$ is defined be $f(x)=(\frac{(1+h(x))^\frac{1}{h(x)}}{e})^\frac{1}{x}$ for every $0 \neq x \in I$

Show that there exists continuous function $g(x)$ on $I$ so that $g(0)=-\frac{1}{2}$ and $f(x)=exp(\frac{h(x)}{x}g(x))$.

so me try do compare $(\frac{(1+h(x))^\frac{1}{h(x)}}{e})^\frac{1}{x}=exp(\frac{h(x)}{x}g(x))$ (because $f(x)=f(x)$) and use $\ln(f(x))$, to isolate $g(x)$ but me get lost. me research question and know that because $h(x)$ continuous than $f(x)=exp(\frac{h(x)}{x}g(x))$ is not continuous because of hole in $x=0$ even although $h(x)$ continuous in $x=0$. So me try isolate $g(x)$ and get lost. me also try put $f(0)$ to show $g(0)=-\frac{1}{2}$ but don't go nowhere.

can you please show me how you solve this hard problem? thank you helping me.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that for $|u|$ small, we have $\ln(1+u)=u-u^2/2+o(u^2)$. Taking logs,
$$\ln f(x) = \frac1{xh(x)}\ln (1+h(x)) - \frac 1x = \frac1x\left(\frac{\ln(1+h(x))}{h(x)} - 1\right).$$
Therefore, using the approximation for $\ln$, we have
$$\ln f(x) = \frac1x\big(\frac{h(x)-h(x)^2/2 + o(h(x)^2)}{h(x)} - 1\big) = \frac1x\big({-}\frac12 h(x)+o(h(x))\big).$$
Now we want this to be equal to $\dfrac{h(x)}xg(x)$ for some continuous function $g$. So we set $g(x) = -\frac12 + \frac{o(h(x))}{h(x)}$ and we're done. Officially, you need to trace through where this term came from. It should be something like
$$g(x) = \begin{cases} -\frac12 + \frac{\ln(1+h(x))-h(x)+h(x)^2/2}{h(x)^2}, & x\ne 0 \\ -\frac12, & x=0 \end{cases}.$$
Now just check that $g$ is continuous. This follows from the original Taylor expansion of $\ln$ which I started with. Alternatively, we could have used
$$g(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{\ln(1+h(x))-h(x)}{h(x)^2}, & x\ne 0 \\ -\frac12, & x=0 \end{cases}.$$